# Process.Start() ing exe doesn't work

Tags: c#, process.start, keylogger

I am using the following line of code to launch a keylogger I made:

```
ProcessStartInfo keylogger = new ProcessStartInfo(@"C:\keylogger.exe");
keylogger.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
Process.Start(keylogger);
```

When I used this code the keylogger launches but doesn't log any keystrokes. I thought this was because of trying to hide the process window, so I changed the code to this:

```
ProcessStartInfo keylogger = new ProcessStartInfo(@"C:\keylogger.exe");
Process.Start(keylogger);
```

Still the same problem, I even tried `Process.Start(@"C:\keylogger.exe");` alone and even that doesn't seem to work.

In all cases the keylogger launches but doesn't record any keystrokes to the log file. But if I double click and open the keylogger it works perfectly fine.

Comment: Did you check the file path? Try it with a full path.

Comment: @Sievajet You mean the run the program as Admin or run the keylogger as admin? When I double click Admin pop up doesn't come up.

Comment: @HwasooLee As I said the keylogger launches, I can see it in the task manager.

Comment: It depends on the UAC settings you have, but try to run the process with admin privileges from within your code

Comment: How are you recording keystrokes?

Comment: Try these keylogger.CreateNoWindow = false;  and keylogger.UseShellExecute = false;

Comment: Does it run on the foreground?

Comment: @Krumelur C++ program using WindowsHook

Comment: @CliveDM Yes...Just doesn't write to the log file.

Comment: @HwasooLee Not working :'(

Comment: @Bauss what is that? lol.

Comment: It's the shutdown command

Comment: write permission to the log file?

Comment: I feel like we shouldn't help you get a "Keylogger" up and running until you tell us how you plan on using it.

Comment: @Tdorno thoughtful! lol

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like all I had to do was change the working directory..lol!

This Code worked:

```
ProcessStartInfo keylogger = new ProcessStartInfo(@"C:\keylogger.exe");
keylogger.WorkingDirectory = @"C:\";
keylogger.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
Process.Start(keylogger);
```

Comment: I like to do it this way: `keylogger.WorkingDirectory = System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(keylogger.FileName);` Then I know the path is correct, and won't be wrong due to a typing error...

Comment: @Idle_Mind Thanks for the advice!

Answer (score 0):

See "To send a keystroke to a different application" on this page:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms171548.aspx

your main issue is that your key logger application is not the running application so it doesn't catch all the keystrokes...

in order to get the keystrokes of all applications you will need to hook into the system kernel, have a look on the following
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/6362/Global-System-Hooks-in-NET

keep in mind:

> System hooks are powerful. And, with that power comes responsibility. When something goes wrong with system hooks, they don't just break your application. They can break every application running on your system. It is unlikely that it would actually come to that extreme. Nonetheless, you need to double and triple check your code when using system hooks.

Comment: So how to overcome this? I did not understand fully.

Comment: Can anyone explain what he is trying to say?